# I have a cloud 9 error while running the app in cloud 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cloud9-ide, cloud9

when I run my app I get this error 
:

```
(NoMethodError in Articles#new
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/yappy/qaucky/app/views/articles/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for #<Article:0x007ff8e20e4b50>
```

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
<h1>Create an article</h1>
   <%= form_for @article do |f| %>
   <% end %>
```

this is the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kghdF.png)

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/yappy/qaucky)

resources :articles

```
root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
```

my new.html.erb file:

```
 <h1>Create an article</h1>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

my articles controller file:
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

```
def new

@article = Article.new 

end





end
```

my article.rb file :

```
class Article 


end
```

my routes.rb file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest 
priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# root 'welcome#index'
resources :articles  

root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

# Example of regular route:
#   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `form_for @article` if `@article` doesn't respond to `model_name` and a couple of other methods that are used by Rails to determine and generate URLs.

Given that your question is tagged with `ruby-on-rails` I guess that you want to store articles in the database. `ActiveRecord::Base` provides this methods. Just inherit from it. Change

```
class Article 
end
```

to

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Note: This only works if there is a table named `articles` in your database.

Comment: i am getting an error that says :                      
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ArticlesController#new
                                                                                                                
     Could not find table 'articles'                                                                                         it is show me my articles controller file: class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def new

@article = Article.new 

end





end

Comment: The error message `Could not find table 'articles'` is quite specific. There is no database table to store the articles you create with the form. Just create a database migration adding the table and the columns you need and run it. See the [Rails Guides about migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Comment: i am trying to make articles from the UI will this still work

Comment: i am a rails newbie so can you please explain that a bit clearer